# How many ways to write $2010$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $ N$ be the number of ways to write $ 2010$ in the form $ 2010 = a_3 \cdot 10^3 + a_2 \cdot 10^2 + a_1 \cdot 10 + a_0$, where the $ a_i$'s are integers, and $ 0 \le a_i \le 99$. An example of such a representation is $ 1\cdot10^3 + 3\cdot10^2 + 67\cdot10^1 + 40\cdot10^0$. Find $ N$.

I picked the biggest $a_1$ so: $a_1 = 2$, there are only two ways to form $2010$.

Take $a_1 = 1$ now. This opens up to a lot of possibilities.

Specific Casework should work:

Cases 1-1: $a_2 = 10$, then possibilities are: $a_1 = 1, a_0 = 0$ or $a_1  = 0, a_0 = 10$

Actually, I think a number-theoretic way is easier.

But still.

Case 1: $a_1 = 1$ then we must solve:

$100x + 10y + z = 1010$.

Since $0 \le x \le 10$, we can casework $x$ so that:

Case 1-1:$x = 0$. So that:

$10y + z = 1010 \implies z \equiv 0 \pmod{10}, z = 10k$ and $y = 101 - k$.

Hence, $(0, 101 - k, 10k)$. $\min{k} = 0 $ and we need to find the max of $k$. We must have, $101 - k \le 99$ and $10k \le 99$. This suggests, $k \le 9$.

Cases 1-2: $x=1$. So that:

$10y + z = 910 \implies z \equiv 0 \pmod{10}$ Again, $z = 10k$ and $y = 91 - k$. Giving a set of $(1, 91 - k, 10k)$.Here again, $\min{k} = 0$ and $10k \le 99$ so $k \le 9$.

I am conjecturing that since we are always increasing $x$ values, the value on the RHS will always be divisible by $10$.

$x = 9$ so that:

$10y + z = 110 \implies z = 10k$ and $y = 11 - k$, which again there are $9$ values.

Except if $x=10$ then there is: $10y + z = 10$ then $z = 10k$ and $y = 1 - k$. Then $k$ must be $1$.

So there are: $10(9) + 1 + 2 = 93$ solutions total.

This is just an attempt!

Bump: anybody have anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generating function for these representations is

$$
\frac{x^{100\cdot1000}-1}{x^{1000}-1}\cdot\frac{x^{100\cdot100}-1}{x^{100}-1}\cdot\frac{x^{100\cdot10}-1}{x^{10}-1}\cdot\frac{x^{100}-1}{x-1}=\frac{x^{100000}-1}{x^{10}-1}\cdot\frac{x^{10000}-1}{x-1}\;,
$$

which is also the generating function for representations of the form $b_1\cdot10+b_0$ with $0\le b_i\le9999$. Since this latter restriction is irrelevant for representations of $2010$, we are simply looking for the number of ways to represent $2010$ by tens and ones. We can have anything from $0$ to $201$ tens, so the number of such representations is $202$.

*In response to Calvin Lin's answer*: The cancellation in the generating functions corresponds to a bijection between the two forms of representation, with $b_1=100a_3+a_1$ and $b_0=100a_2+a_0$.

Comment: Interesting approach!

Comment: (+1) I am  particularly interested here, how did you find that generating function?

Comment: @Amad27: The generating function for representations by thousands is

$$1+x^{1000}+x^{2\cdot1000}+\cdots=\frac1{1-x^{1000}}\;.$$

If there is a limitation that we can only use up to $99$ thousands, we have to truncate the generating function:

$$1+x^{1000}+x^{2\cdot1000}+\cdots+x^{99\cdot1000}=\frac{1-x^{100\cdot1000}}{1-x^{1000}}\;.$$

See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation.

Comment: Yes, but why are we using the "thousands?"

Comment: @Amad27: Because the problem says so: "write $2010$ in the form $2010 = a_3 \cdot 10^3 + a_2 \cdot 10^2 + a_1 \cdot 10 + a_0$" -- i.e., represent $2010$ in terms of thousands, hundreds, tens and ones.

Comment: So how did you form a generating function overall? @joriki?

Comment: @Amad27: I don't understand the question. How do you mean, overall?

Comment: How do you form any generating function @joriki?

Comment: Having found the likelihood of a simplification, it is good to check if there is an actual bijection that we can establish. See my solution.

Comment: @Amad27: Comments are not the right place to ask very general questions like how to form any generating function. They should only be used if there's something specific in the answer that seems unclear or dubious and should be clarified or corrected or improved. If you have a more general question, or if you don't understand part of the answer and this seems likely to be due to a lack of knowledge on your part and not due to an unclarity or error in the answer, you should post the question as a question of your own.

Comment: @Amad27: In the meantime, you wrote elsewhere that you understand how to use generating functions. In that case, unfortunately I again don't understand your question "How do you form any generating function?". Please consider taking more care in formulating your questions and asking them more sparingly -- you're taking up a lot of space, time and attention with your comments. You can post separate questions of your own about things you don't understand in answers to other questions; this should only be done in comments if the result is likely to clarify or improve the answer for others.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to start from the other end.  We observe first that $a_0$ can be any multiple of $10$ from $0$ through $90$.  There are, of course, ten such values.

Then $a_1$ can be any one- or two-digit value equivalent to $11-(a_0/10) \bmod 10$.  Again, there are ten such values.

The choices of $a_2$ are much more limited by the fact that the target sum is only $2010$.  In which cases are there two different values?  In which cases are there three?

Once $a_0, a_1, a_2$ have been decided, there is only one usable value of $a_3$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [bijection](https://brilliant.org/wiki/bijection-injection-and-surjection/) approach, which is hinted at by Joriki's solution.

Let $a_i = 10 b_i + c_i$, where $ 0 \leq c_i \leq 9$, $ 0 \leq b_i \leq 9$.

Then, we have

$$2010 = 10 (1000b_3 + 100 b_2 + 10b_1 + b_0) + ( 1000 c_3 + 100 c_2 + 10 c_1 + c_0)$$

Thus, given any representation of $2010 = 10 B + C $, there is a unique corresponding $b_i, c_i$ (clearly the digits of B and C) that we can create, and vice versa. This establishes the bijection. Hence, the answer is 202.

Comment: Nice interpretatino of Joriki's approach!

Comment: The bijection that I had in mind was $2010=10(100a_3+a_1)+(100a_2+a_0)$. I think that corresponds more closely with the cancellation of factors in the generating functions?

Comment: @joriki, the coefficient $A(k)$ is the number of ways. So if for example I am finding how many ways to use the $1000$ it would be $A(1000)x^{1000} = 3x^{1000}$ right ? But you have something way different?

Comment: @Amad27: Again, unfortunately I don't understand your question. Generally speaking, you've been asking a lot of questions in comments recently. Questions in comments are OK, but should usually only be asked if it seems likely that others might have the same question and thus the comment is likely to help clarify the answer. Most of your comments, as far as I could tell, seemed to be based on a misunderstanding or lack of understanding on your part and should preferably have been asked as separate questions so as not to clutter the comments.

Comment: @joriki, I know how to use generating functions, but I just don't understand what you were doing

Comment: @Amad27: Please stop sprinkling comments all over the place like that. Your question about generating functions was under my answer, not here; this comment is out of context and unnecessarily confusing and distracting for others.

Comment: @joriki Oh haha, yes that works too! You should edit that into your solution, with the cancellation reference.

Comment: @CalvinLin: Ok, I did.

Answer (score 1):

In short we have to calculate the number of integer solutions of the Diophantine equation $$1000x+100y+10z+w=2010$$ with the conditions
$0\leq x,y,z,w \leq 99$.
We have $0\leq x\leq 2$ which gives the three equations
$$(1)……100y+10z+w=2010$$     $$(2)……100y+10z+w=1010$$   $$(3)……100y+10z+w=10$$
The equation (3) gives just **two solutions** $(2,0,1,0)$ and $(2,0,0,10)$.

It remains to compute solutions of (1) and (2). We have for $w$ only ten possible values $w=0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90$ which gives for (1) the ten equations $ (1’)……100y+10z=2010,2000,1990,1980,1970,1960,1950,1940,1930,1920$ that is $$(1’)……10y+z=201,200,199,198,197,196,195,194,193,192$$
And for (2) the ten equations $(2’)……100y+10z=1010,1000,990,980,970,960,950,940,930,920$
that is $$(2’)………10y+z=101,100,99,98,97,96,95,94,93,92$$

The first equation of (1’), $10y+z=201$, gives for $z$  only the ten possible values $1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91$ with corresponding unique values of y respectively equal to $20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11$ so ten solutions.

The second one,$10y+z=200$ makes $z=0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90$ which gives for $y$ the values $20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11$ so ten solutions.

Pursuing, $10y+z=199$ makes $z=9,19,29,……….,99$ which give ten solutions and so are for the remaining values $198,197,196,195,194,193,192$.

Thus the ten equations (1’) give **one hundred solutions**.
The same procedure goes for ten equations (2’) which give then **one hundred solutions.**

Finally we have $2+100+100=202$ solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that's not particularly elegant but gives the right answer (checked by brute force).

First express each coefficient uniquely as $b_i\cdot 10 + a_i$.

$2010 = b_3 \cdot 10^4 + a_3 \cdot 10^3 + b_2 \cdot 10^3 + a_2 \cdot 10^2 +
b_1 \cdot 10^2 + a_1 \cdot 10 + b_0 \cdot 10 + a_0$.

We must have $b_3 = 0, a_0 = 0$, so

$201 = (a_3 + b_2) \cdot 10^2 + (a_2 + b_1) \cdot 10^1 + (a_1 + b_0)$.

Each coefficient is in $0, \ldots, 18$.

If $a_3 + b_2 = 1$, then $101 = (a_2 + b_1) \cdot 10^1 + (a_1 + b_0)$. We have
$a_2 + b_1 = 9, a_1 + b_0 = 11$ or $a_2 + b_1 = 10, a_1 + b_0 = 1$, this gives
$2 \cdot (10 \cdot 8 + 9 \cdot 2) = 196$ solutions.

If $a_3 + b_2 = 2$, then $1 = (a_2 + b_1) \cdot 10^1 + (a_1 + b_0)$. We have
$a_2 + b_1 = 0, a_1 + b_0 = 1$, this gives $3 \cdot 2 = 6$ solutions.

So together we have 202 solutions.

Comment: I get the same result that you do, so I think we're on the right track!

Comment: Good to know you got the same result!

Comment: On the right track at the start, but your cases become complicated. See my solution.